# Converting bones transformation matrix from OpenGL to Blender

Tags: animation, rigging, opengl, conversion, matrix

So, I'm trying to convert some transformation matrices from OpenGL to Blender but bone poses are wrong. I assume it's transformation matrix, I'm no expert in OpenGl but it's used in this function:

`glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader_character->program, "joints"), Character::JOINT_NUM, GL_FALSE, (float*)character->joint_mesh_xform);`

So I assume it's transformation matrix also I've tested it's moving bones.
But when applying those values to my rig, position is weird:
[image: How it looks in Blender]

Compared to OpenGL:
[image: How it looks in OpenGL]

I've tried applying it directly with bone.matrix_basis and all axis configurations when applying rotation (like (X, -Z, Y) in Blender but none of achieved poses looks right.
Also for same matrix:

```
<Matrix 4x4 (  0.9997,  0.0193, -0.0118, 0.0000)
            ( -0.0189,  0.9994,  0.0289, 0.0000)
            (  0.0124, -0.0287,  0.9995, 0.0000)
            (-23.8805, -7.8834, -0.4667, 1.0000)>
```

Blender produces different results (using matrix.to_euler()):

```
(-0.028720224, -0.012384685, -0.01894982)
```

OpenGL (using glm::extractEulerAngleXYZ()):

```
(0.02872, 0.012385, 0.01895)
```

How to achieve same pose as in OpenGL having only this transformation matrix?

[Original project in OpenGL](https://github.com/sreyafrancis/PFNN/blob/master/demo/pfnn.cpp)

Also linking .blend file with full data form OpenGL and rig:
[Link to .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BL7r7Wy40iumiy6tiovoAb6JE26bQyGi/view?usp=sharing)

Edit_1:

I'm not sure but do I need to recalculate matrices earlier?
I'm calculating new rotations for child bones using this code:

```
def forward_kinematics(self):
    for i in range(self.JOINT_NUM):
        self.joint_global_anim_xform[i] = self.joint_anim_xform[i]
        self.joint_global_rest_xform[i] = self.joint_rest_xform[i]
        j = int(self.joint_parents[i])
        while j != -1:
            self.joint_global_anim_xform[i] = self.joint_global_anim_xform[i] @ self.joint_anim_xform[j]
            self.joint_global_rest_xform[i] = self.joint_global_rest_xform[i] @ self.joint_rest_xform[j]
            j = int(self.joint_parents[j])
​
        self.joint_mesh_xform[i] = self.joint_global_rest_xform[i].inverted() @ self.joint_global_anim_xform[i]
```

And I'm applying rotations using this code:

```
def apply_rotations(self, frame :int):
    for bone in self.armature.pose.bones:
        ind = self.bones.get(bone.name, -1)
        if ind != -1:
            bone.matrix_basis = mat.Matrix(self.joint_mesh_xform[ind])
```

Matrices used here have exact same values as ones used in OpenGL version

Edit_2:

Class definition for ealier code:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.JOINT_NUM = 31
        self.joint_anim_xform = np.empty(self.JOINT_NUM, dtype=mat.Matrix)
        self.joint_rest_xform = np.empty(self.JOINT_NUM, dtype=mat.Matrix)
        self.joint_mesh_xform = np.empty(self.JOINT_NUM, dtype=mat.Matrix)
        self.joint_global_rest_xform = np.empty(self.JOINT_NUM, dtype=mat.Matrix)
        self.joint_global_anim_xform = np.empty(self.JOINT_NUM, dtype=mat.Matrix)
        self.joint_parents = [0] * self.JOINT_NUM
```

`rest_xform` are default bones positions,
`anim_xform` are calculated bones positions

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Blender matrices are defined in row order.  Eg https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/192754/15543  Looks like it may need to  be transposed.  As explained here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/192754/15543 the transpose of ortho matrix is also inverse. yet the 3x3 rotation matrix of above is not orthogonal.  As a test if you set matrix above to matrix world of an object it will be converted such that it is orthogonal.

Comment: I've tried transposing matrix with little to no success.

You mean object.matrix_world? 
But PoseBones I'm assigning don't have that property. Only matrix, matrix_basis and matrix_channel.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, was suggestion re setting a matrix of cube or empty to matrix above by way of example.  Eg in py console assign it `C.object.matrix_world = M` and then look at value of `C.object.matrix_world`  Same principal as bone matrices. Blender expects the 3x3 rotation part to be orthogonal, and the translation to be in 4th column.

Comment: It returned:
```<Matrix 4x4 (  0.9997,  0.0193, -0.0118, 0.0000), 
( -0.0189,  0.9994,  0.0289, 0.0000), 
(  0.0124, -0.0287,  0.9995, 0.0000), 
(-23.8805, -7.8834, -0.4667, 1.0000)>```
 So I don't think it's converting this matrix

Comment: https://pasteall.org/Zvjb

Comment: Your setup is giving same result as my last comment
https://pasteall.org/UcP5

Comment: No it bloody isn't. The two matrices printed in https://pasteall.org/Zvjb are not the same. Anyway I'm done with trying to help here.... "_I've tried and it didn't help_"

Comment: No, they are not the same but code form your snippet is not converting my matrix. Please look at my code, I've updated it with print results
https://pasteall.org/Zhe7#L1,2,8,9,3,6,11
Maybe I'm doing something wrong and not seeing it

Comment: Ok, I've tried your solution in python interactive console and it gives same result as your snippet. But when I do same thing in python file, matrix is not converted.
Am I missing an import or something?

Comment: Thanks for help anyway, I found out that I need to call ```bpy.context.view_layer.update()``` for ```matrix_world``` to be recalculated. But that didn't help with overall result pose

Comment: Thankyou,  not necessary to inform me, am already aware of view layer update.  To re-iterate, (ie back to comment one) the matrix in question is in column order, and needs to be transposed to be a valid transformation matrix in blender.. The translation is (-23, -7,  0). Using as a matrix without transposing obliterates the translation and inverts the rotation (if ortho).  Notice how the two euler rotations in question are inverses of each other. .... get it??????  Setting a matrix world was to demo this Btw the code posted in edit, is somewhat meaningless without seeing the class definition.

Comment: I just thought I should clarify what was wrong in my code.
I think I get this, after transposing my angles are now similar to those from OpenGl, yet pose still does not look right.
I've added class definition but adding how each variable is calculated would be too much code cause I'm using neural network to calculate this